# Magento Captcha

Tags: php, gd, captcha

In Magento I want to Implement Captcha.I have the CaptchaSecurityImages.php in my templates/cms/mycaptcha directory. In the same directory i have myform.phtml. What I am trying to achieve is

```
    <img src="CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&height=40&characters=5" />
```

I am not getting anything.I have also included the monofont.ttf file in this directory.What do i need to do in order to get the captcha working

I am using the following captcha

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-captcha.php

Whiich works absolutely fine for all my php forms. Please help.

Comment: what happens when you point your browser to the mentioned captcha URL - CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&height=40&characters=5?

Comment: You most probably don't have GD enabled.

Comment: Not sure why the Magento tag is on this question.

Answer (score 1):

In magento, the proper way to accomplish this would be to create a new block. But if you want to do it in a quick-and-dirty way you can copy the file CaptchaSecurityImages.php wherever you want, for example in the root folder of your project. Then it will be accesible directly from the browser http://xxxxx/CaptchaSecurityImages.php.

If you don't see anything (blank screen, not a 404 error) I think there is an error in that file. To see the problem you can force PHP to show errors adding this in the begining of the PHP file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was produced because it was missing the activation of extension `extension=php_gd2.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Here there is an explanation of how to use CAPTA-Technique in Magento 1.7+

http://www.cartware.de/blog/detail/article/captcha-feature-aus-magento-17-in-eigenem-modul-einsetzen/

Its in German but by reading the code you may get the clue…